# Composition law in the colored operad whose algebras are (symmetric) operads

Tags: co.combinatorics, operads

In Berger-Moerdijk, Resolution of coloured operads and rectification of homotopy algebras (1.5.6) there is a description of the operad, whose algebras are non-colored symmetric operads.

I have some trouble understanding how the composition law in this operad works.

Is it true that in the result of composition $(T,\sigma, \tau)$ of some labeled trees $(T_i,\sigma_i,\tau_i)$ the planar tree $T$ and the labeling of vertices $\sigma$ depend only on $T_i$ and $\sigma_i$?

What is the correct labeling of input edges of trees on the right side?

[image: some hand-drawn graphics]

Comment: You might consider looking at one of the books Donald Yau has written, e.g. his one with Mark Johnson (though Yau now has a solo-authored book on 1-colored operads too). They are very careful about spelling out how to get from the trees to the algebraic structure, including the composition law. This is a tricky step and it does not hurt to read about it in several places as you work it out.

Comment: That might be not what you are looking for, but in http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.02701 Deling&Vallette described "the" colored operad of symmetric operads pretty well and moreover considered its curved Koszul theory.

Comment: Thanks. Using Dehling-Vallette paper it is possible to figure out how composition in terms of labeled planar trees works.